# using axios inside of other axios function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I couldn't really find better title for my question but here is what happened. so, I created a custom hook for my login in react like this:

`useLogin.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";
import useGetUserImage from "hooks/useGetUserImage/useGetUserImage";
export const useLogin = () => {
  const [userName, setUserName] = React.useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState();
  const [snack, setSnack] = React.useState(false);
  const [zoom, setZoom] = React.useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const cookieFn = (data) => {
    Cookies.set("user", JSON.stringify(data), {
      path: "/",
      expires: 3,
      sameSite: "strict",
      secure: window.top.location.protocol === "https:",
    });
  };
  const { ImageFetchingHandler } = useGetUserImage();
  const HandleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (Boolean(userName) && Boolean(password))
      axios
        .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL_API_LOGIN}`, {
          softWareOrUser: false,
          userName: userName,
          password: password,
        })
        .then((r) => {
          if (r.data.resCode === 1) {
            ImageFetchingHandler(r.data);
            cookieFn(r.data.Data);
            setSnack(false);
          } else {
            setSnack(true);
          }
        })
        .then(() => {
          navigate({ pathname: "/main" });
        })

        .catch((e) => {
          throw new Error(e.message);
        });
    else {
     alert("fill empty fields");
    }
  };
  return {
    HandleLogin,
    snack,
    zoom,
    setUserName,
    setPassword,
    setZoom,
    setSnack,
  };
};
```

as you can see there's another hook inside of my `useLogin.js` called `useGetUserImage`.

I need to get user Image whenever I signed in and got Bearer token but there are 2 problems.

first of all because I will receive a base64 text, I will have delay.

and second, I need to call it right after I logged in. which causes error in `img` tag. because the `src` will be undefined until I get my base64.

here is my `useGetUserImage`

```
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
const useGetUserImage = () => {
  const ImageFetchingHandler = ({ token }) => {
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL_API_FETCH_IMAGE}`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "DotNet-Timeout": 30000,
      },
      data: JSON.stringify({
        id: "4",
      }),
    }).then((d) => {
      Cookies.set("userImage", JSON.stringify(d.data), {
        path: "/",
        expires: 3,
        sameSite: "strict",
        secure: window.top.location.protocol === "https:",
      });
    });
  };
  return { ImageFetchingHandler };
};

export default useGetUserImage;
```

is there any way to handle this problem?

I tried to add such thing to my `mainpage.js` but it didn't work. for some reason it passes my condition although when `userImage` is undefined

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (
      Cookies.get("user") === undefined ||
      Cookies.get("userImage" === undefined)
    ) {
      navigate({ pathname: "/Login" });
    } else {
      console.log(Cookies.get("userImage"));
      setuserImage(JSON.parse(Cookies.get("user")));
    }
  }, [navigate]);
```

I mean `userImage` is still undefined but it will go `else` block

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the cookie should be your primary source to the image, it should rather be a state. Then instead of writing it to the cookie you write it to the state. Now when you receive the image, necessary parts of the application is updated, something you can't really achieve if you write the image to a cookie. With this approach you can write a `useEffect` that tries to read the cookie on start up and initiate the state with it, and a `useEffect` that writes it to the cookie everytime it changes.

Two other thoughts:

- You have a misplaced `)` in the `useEffect`: `Cookies.get("userImage" === undefined)` vs `Cookies.get("userImage") === undefined`
- `useGetUserImage` isn't a hook, as it's not using any other hooks. It's just an ordinary function, you can use it as you do, but to avoid confusion you should maybe call it `getUserImage` or something similar.

Comment: well, if I save image base64 in my state. everything will gone on refresh and I don't want that. also all data will be saved so user won't need to login each time.

Comment: also I wonder why `getuserimage` is not a hook?

Comment: you can build custom hook for yourself. it isn't built in hook but I made it for myself

Comment: as i wrote above you can store it in a cookie and write it to the state on startup, then it won't be gone on refresh.

Comment: but result will be the same. it will take time for cookie to set, and this delay will cause same problem

Comment: a hook always uses other hooks internally. `useGetUserImage` never use any other hooks which make's it an ordinary function (which is a good thing, then you can use it more freely). https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html